# Cannot resolve symbol SaveChangesAsync

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem with the .NET Core and Entity Framework.
I created myself the .NET Core project, I added `DbContext` and all the rest. My problem is that I can download the data without the slightest problem, unfortunately I can not save them, i.e. I have the `Add` method, but I do not have the `SaveChanges` method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

using CRM.Model.Entities;

namespace CRM.Model.Concrete
{
    public abstract class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubcategoryL2> SubcategoriesL2 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Coupon> Coupons { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<SubcategoryL2>().ToTable("Subs");
            #region "Seed Data"

            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
                new { Id = "1", Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
                new { Id = "2", Name = "User", NormalizedName = "USER" }
            );

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

ICouponRepository

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CRM.Model.Concrete;

namespace CRM.Repository.Abstract
{
    public interface ICouponRepository
    {
        Task AddCoupon(Coupon coupon);
    }
}
```

CouponRepository

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CRM.Model.Concrete;
using CRM.Repository.Abstract;

namespace CRM.Repository.Concrete
{
    public class CouponRepository : ICouponRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationContext _applicationContext;

        public CouponRepository(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            _applicationContext = applicationContext;
        }

        public async Task AddCoupon(Coupon coupon)
        {
           await _applicationContext.Coupons.AddAsync(coupon);
           await _applicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is here in CouponRepository, i.e. 
[image]

I have no idea how I can fix it and why it does not work :(

> CS1061 The "ApplicationContext" element does not contain the
>   definition of "SaveChangesAsync" and the available "SaveChangesAsync"
>   extension method was not found, which takes the first argument of the
>   "ApplicationContext" type (does not the using directive or the kit
>   reference?).

Second error

> CS0012 C # The "IdentityDbContext <>" type is defined in an
>   unreferenced set. You must add a reference to the set
>   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, Version = 2.2.0.0,
>   Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = adb9793829ddae60"

My project is divided into several smaller ones, that is, the main CRM project. In it there are several smaller ones:

- CRM.Core
- CRM.Services
- CRM.Repository
- CRM.Resources
- CRM.Model

The problem is that without the slightest problem I use the ApplicationContext to retrieve data from the database, unfortunately I can not save any data with it, because the error pops up like in the picture.

when i change

> public abstract class ApplicationContext :
>   IdentityDbContext

to

> public abstract class ApplicationContext : DbContext

then all is Ok, but then Identity will not work for me

**Solution:**
The solution to my problem was to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore package through the NuGet Package.

Comment: Follow the suggestion in the second error and I bet the first will go away too.

Comment: I can't add this because my project contains a few others

Comment: @KirkLarkin i edit my first post and add more details

Comment: Next time, don't change your question halfway through, it's not fair to people who have spent the time to give you answers to the original problem. For example, my answer give you your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the second error message it is clear what you have to do. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` nuget package to the project where `CouponRepository`  is located as follows:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.0
```

Or you can also add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` meta-package to your `CouponRepository` project by adding the following item.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The error should go away now!

Comment: Hi,
Yesterday, in this way, it was a solution and in my post at the bottom I wrote to others how I solved my problem.

Comment: Yeh! I noticed this after posting the answer. By the way, hope my answer will help someone with the same problem come to your question. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, I will mark your answer as a solution to the problem because in this way I fixed this error yesterday, i.e. it was enough to install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore package for CouponRepository and the problem was solved. After all, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to be calling `SaveChangesAsync` against the context, not the `DbSet`, so you should be writing this:

```
await _applicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Secondly, as a bonus, you shouldn't be using `AddAsync` unless you really need to, you should be doing this:

```
_applicationContext.Coupons.Add(coupon);
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-2.1) state:

> This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.

Comment: Well, I just did it and there is the same error all the time as in the picture.

Comment: I can't see how that is the case, can you show the exact error message you get with my code?

Comment: See the picture that I put in my post, the one at the bottom. All the time such a mistake indicates.

Comment: CS0012 C # The "IdentityDbContext <>" type is defined in an unreferenced set. You must add a reference to the set "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore, Version = 2.2.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = adb9793829ddae60".